# Concatenating strings with foldr in SML

Tags: string, concatenation, sml, fold

I'm trying to declare a function, string list -> string, that with the input for instance 
`["Chicago","city","USA"]` should return `"Chicago city USA"`. What I did so far was this:

```
fun gather ts = foldr op ^ "" ts;
```

This seems to be somewhat along the lines, however the problem is, I would like to include the spaces between the words, as this function would return `"ChigagocityUSA"`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the problem is that `^` is a function that for two strings "foo" and "bar" returns "foobar", although you want "foo bar".

So what you need to do is to define a function that takes two string arguments (as a tuple) and returns the two strings with a space in between them (so `string1 ^ " " ^ string2`).

You can then give that function as an argument to `foldr` and get the result you want.

Comment: i cant really get it to work, i made a new function fun hj ts = fn(a,b) => (a^" "^b);

Comment: @user: Not sure what the `ts` is for since you don't use it. You can just do `val hj = fn (a,b) => (a^" "^b)` or `fun hj (a,b) = (a^" "^b)`, which is the same, but shorter. Then `foldr hj "" ts`, works fine.

Comment: Ah ofcourse, thanks a bunch. Is there a short way around removing the last space that occurs?

Comment: perhaps instead of fun hj (a,b) = (a^" "^b) i could use something like fun hj (a,_) = a   | (a,b) => a^" "^b); ?

Comment: yes that works, but with (a,"") instead of (a,_) thanx for the help mate:)

Comment: @user: Yes, exactly, except that `_` does not mean "empty string". If you replace `_` with `""` (which does mean "empty string"), it will work.

Comment: @user: Do consider clicking the green check mark next to my answer to indicate that it solved your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use `hd` and `tl` to get inital values for `fold`.  This avoids having a leading or trailing blank character in the result.   `foldl` is useful if you want to think left-to-right.

Definition:

```
fun gather xs = 
      foldl (fn (x,acc) =>
                acc  ^ " " ^ x) (hd xs) (tl xs)
```

Usage:

```
- gather ["what", "is", "this", "gather"];
val it = "what is this gather" : string
-
```