# SML - a small problem

Tags: sml

I have given : spacegather : string list -> string

I have to make a function, so it turns the call:

spacegather ["I", "am", "nice"] to -> "I am nice"

thanx

Comment: See the question [SML question about foldr](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900369/sml-question-about-foldr), which was presumably asked by another student working on the same assignment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me see if i get this right:

```
fun spacegather (h::[]) = h 
| spacegather (h::tl) = h ^ " " ^ (spacegather tl);

spacegather ["I", "am", "nice!!"];
```

Output: val it = "I am nice!!" : string

This should do it, right?

Answer (score 2):

```
intercalate xs xss = concat (intersperse xs xss)
```

Find the practical meaning of intercalate.  Here is intersperse:

```
(*intersperse x [a,b,c..,z]=>[a,x,b,x,c,x..,x,z]*)

fun intersperse y  nil = nil
  | intersperse y [x] = [x]
  | intersperse y (x::xs)=x::y::(intersperse y xs)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String.concatWith " " ["I", "am", "nice"]
```